# new field not showing up in Solr

Tags: solr

our Solr schema is open so we dont need to define a new particular field.

when I send a Json request to sava a new document to Solr, I added a new field `lang_sx` and I do :

```
UpdateResponse response = server.addBeans(list);
System.out.println(response.getStatus());
server.commit();
```

`response.getStatus()` shows me that the request was successful but I don't see this new field in Solr.

Comment: One reason could be stored = false for that field.

Comment: I think System.out.println(response.getStatus()); should be after commit.